# How to hide messages, contacts etc folder using J2ME Code ?

Tags: java-me, nokia

I used J2ME approx 3 year ago, so I have not updated knowledge about it. Can anybody tell me is it possible to create an app for my Nokia handset such that I can lock my sensitive folders such as messages, contacts, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can hide your folder using FileConnection API  and also manage contacts using PIM API
but hiding message are not possible in J2ME.

Comment: Can I provide password lock to the folders?

Comment: You can only show and hide using FileConnection API but if you want password prompt then you can implement it manually